# Get 3-letter month abbreviation for previous month in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet with individual tables named `DEC19`, `JAN20`, `FEB20` etc.

Each of these sheets contains the first and last days in the respective month as dates, so e.g. sheet `JAN20` has `1/1/2020` in cell A5.

What I would like is an automatic way to reference the previous sheet via an `INDIRECT( prevMonthAsMMMYY(A5) & "!F195" )`. Without resorting to macros, how can I achieve this `prevMonthAsMMMYY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=INDIRECT(TEXT("1/"&MONTH(LEFT(A47, 3)&1)-1, "mmm"&RIGHT(A47, 2))&"!F195")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Ah nice, I didn't know that TEXT has a parameter for the target format. This solution helps, it's incomplete for mapping Jan20 to Dec19, but I figured that out myself. A question: Does `LEFT(...)&1` do what I think, and appends a 1? Is that to become any recognized date format, i.e. a month in year 1?

Comment: not rly, `&1` forces to convert month in `MMMM` or `MMM` format into number `=MONTH("AUG"&1)` will become `8`

Comment: OK, but `=MONTH("AUG1")` also returns 8. Why not `=MONTH("AUG")`? Because it's lacking a year, I would assume. By appending 1, you append sth that can be parsed as a year.

Comment: ...or possibly as a day, not a year.